# How to get react native icons working in project created by react native Cli?

Tags: react-native

I am using react native vector icons in React Native Cli project. I am facing the following issue.
Here is my error

[image: This is the snap of my error]

I am using React Native 0.60 so I don't need to link the library. I also did pod install in my iOS project.
I also added the following in the `info.plist` file of my iOS project

```
<key>UIAppFonts</key>
<array>
<string>AntDesign.ttf</string>
<string>Entypo.ttf</string>
<string>EvilIcons.ttf</string>
<string>Feather.ttf</string>
<string>FontAwesome.ttf</string>
<string>FontAwesome5_Brands.ttf</string>
<string>FontAwesome5_Regular.ttf</string>
<string>FontAwesome5_Solid.ttf</string>
<string>Foundation.ttf</string>
<string>Ionicons.ttf</string>
<string>MaterialCommunityIcons.ttf</string>
<string>MaterialIcons.ttf</string>
<string>Octicons.ttf</string>
<string>SimpleLineIcons.ttf</string>
<string>Zocial.ttf</string>
</array>
```

For Android in `app/bulid.gradle` I added

```
apply from: "../../node_modules/react-native-vector-icons/fonts.gradle"

import React from "react";
import { View, Text, StyleSheet } from "react-native";
import {Feather} from 'react-native-vector-icons';
const SearchBar = () => {
return ( <View style={styles.background}>
<Feather name="search" />
<Text>Search Bar</Text> </View> ); };
```

Still I am facing the same issue

If I comment the line `<Feather name="search" />` then my app works fine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put it in the `text`.

```js
import Icon from 'react-native-vector-icons/Ionicons';
...
const SearchBar = () => {
return ( <View style={styles.background}>

<Text> <Icon name="search" /> Search Bar</Text> </View> ); };
```

[Here's an example](https://snack.expo.io/@taeeh/inline-icons-example) of what I've created.

```js
import React from 'react';
import { Ionicons } from '@expo/vector-icons';
import {View,Text} from "react-native"


const SearchBar = () => {
return ( <View style={{backgroundColor:"red",width:"50%"}}>

<Text> <Ionicons name="md-checkmark-circle" /> Search Bar</Text> </View> ); };


export default class IconExample extends React.Component {



  render() {
    return (
      <View style={{flex:1,alignItems:"center",justifyContent:"center"}}>
      {SearchBar()}
      <Ionicons name="md-checkmark-circle" size={32} color="green" />
      </View>
      );
  }
}
```

Comment: @Nudge I made an example for you and a link to see it. Please check my answer.

Comment: I don't want to use Expo. Even I got it running in Expo. I am using react native cli

Comment: @Nudge This is simply using the Expo icon module to use the snack.

Comment: Use your React-native Icon Module instead of Expo's Icon Module.

Comment: @Nudge And use ICON, not Feather. Look at my answer.

Comment: Can you use ICON in a module as normal react-native-vector-icons?